# How do I get certain parts of an array and output into a string?

Tags: php

From an API I get this output: `{ "results": 1, "data": [ "EGLL 072120Z AUTO 04006KT 9999 NCD 13/06 Q1026" ] }`.
Which I then manage to get into an Array: `Array ( [0] => { "results" [1] => 1, "data" [2] => [ "EGLL 072120Z AUTO 04006KT 9999 NCD 13/06 Q1026" ] } )`.
But then I want to only output it so it only says `EGLL 072120Z AUTO 04006KT 9999 NCD 13/06 Q1026` without all the symbols.
Tried `Array_slice` and explode but i cant figure out if thats the correct way or if I am doing something wrong

```
<?php 


$icao = $_GET['ap'];

$ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.checkwx.com/metar/'.$icao.'/?pretty=1');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['X-API-Key: ']);

  $result = curl_exec ($ch);
  curl_close ($ch);

 echo $result;

  $exp = explode(":", $result);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form action="/index.php">
  Airport:<br>
  <input type="text" name="ap" value="">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 
<br>
<? echo print_r($exp, true);?>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

My index.php

Comment: *Which I then manage to get into an Array: Array ( [0] => { "results" [1] => 1, "data" [2] => [ "EGLL 072120Z AUTO 04006KT 9999 NCD 13/06 Q1026" ] } )* Did you use `json_decode` (not shown in your snippet)? So, why don't you just access `$jsonvar[0]['data']` (or iterate over all the records)?

Comment: In order to provide a [mcve] please hardcode `$result = curl_exec ($ch);` with an actual curl result, since you need to register on checkwx.com and request an API key to send it via `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['X-API-Key: my-personal-api-key']);`.Then show the code how you got an PHP array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the response below is json:

> { "results": 1, "data": [ "EGLL 072120Z AUTO 04006KT 9999 NCD 13/06 Q1026" ] }

Which looks like this (visualised):

[image]

I don't know the API, but it looks like it returns an array of string values inside the field `data`.

So, what you want to do after making the api call first to decode the json response like this:

```
$response = json_decode($result);
```

if you only want the first element in the array of `data` field, then do this:

```
echo $response->data[0];
```

If you want to iterate over it; then do this:

```
foreach ($response->data as $item) {
    echo $item . "<br>";
}
```